# How to Remove the last few characters from console Python?

Tags: python, console

I am making a little math game, similar to [zeta mac](https://arithmetic.zetamac.com/game?key=a7220a92). Everything seems to be working well. Ideally I would like this console output to erase incorrect answers entered by the user, without reprinting the math problem again for them to solve. Is something like this possible?

For example, I may prompt the user to answer "57 + 37 = " in the console, then if they type 24 (console would look like this "57 + 37 = 24", I would like the 24 to be erased, and for the "57 + 37 = " to remain, allowing the user to guess again, without the same equation having to be printed again on a line below.

Here is the source code (sorry if its messy, I just started learning python):

```
import random
import time


def play(seconds):
    start_time = time.time()
    score = 0
    while True:
        current_time = time.time()
        elapsed_time = current_time - start_time
        a = random.randint(2, 100)
        b = random.randint(2, 100)
        d = random.randint(2, 12)
        asmd = random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4])
        if (asmd == 1):
            solve = a + b 
            answer  = input("%d + %d = " % (a, b))
        elif (asmd == 2):
            if (a > b):
                solve = a - b
                answer  = input("%d - %d = " % (a, b))
            else:
                solve = b - a
                answer  = input("%d - %d = " % (b, a))
        elif (asmd == 3):
            solve = a * d
            answer  = input("%d * %d = " % (a, d))
        else:
            solve = d
            c = a * d
            answer  = input("%d / %d = " % (c, a))
    
             
        while (solve != int(answer)):
            answer = input("= ")   
        score += 1
        if elapsed_time > seconds:
            print("Time\'s up! Your score was %d." % (score))
            break  


play(10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use add these two lines after **answer = input("= ")**:

> sys.stdout.write("\033[F") #back to previous line

> sys.stdout.write("\033[K") #clear line

```
import random
import time
import sys

def play(seconds):
    start_time = time.time()
    score = 0
    while True:
        current_time = time.time()
        elapsed_time = current_time - start_time
        a = random.randint(2, 100)
        b = random.randint(2, 100)
        d = random.randint(2, 12)
        asmd = random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4])
        if (asmd == 1):
            solve = a + b 
            answer  = input("%d + %d = " % (a, b))                            
        elif (asmd == 2):
            if (a > b):
                solve = a - b
                answer  = input("%d - %d = " % (a, b))
            else:
                solve = b - a
                answer  = input("%d - %d = " % (b, a))
        elif (asmd == 3):
            solve = a * d
            answer  = input("%d * %d = " % (a, d))
        else:
            solve = d
            c = a * d
            answer  = input("%d / %d = " % (c, a))
    
             
        while (solve != int(answer)):
            answer = input("= ") 
            if solve != int(answer):  
                sys.stdout.write("\033[F") #back to previous line 
                sys.stdout.write("\033[K") #clear line
            
        score += 1
        if elapsed_time > seconds:
            print("Time\'s up! Your score was %d." % (score))
            break  


play(10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing characters from the end of the input is probably not the best approach as you aren't quite sure how many characters there will be (*depends on the number*).

The answer from @QualidSai does clear the terminal but it doesn't show your formula string again. To solve this I'd store the formula string that you print as part of your input as a string variable, then you can use that when looping. For example:

```py
import random
import time
import sys

def play(seconds):
    start_time = time.time()
    score = 0
    while True:
        current_time = time.time()
        elapsed_time = current_time - start_time
        a = random.randint(2, 100)
        b = random.randint(2, 100)
        d = random.randint(2, 12)
        asmd = random.choice([1, 2, 3, 4])
        if (asmd == 1):
            solve = a + b 
            question = "%d + %d = " % (a, b)
        elif (asmd == 2):
            if (a > b):
                solve = a - b
                question = "%d - %d = " % (a, b)
            else:
                solve = b - a
                question = "%d - %d = " % (b, a)
        elif (asmd == 3):
            solve = a * d
            question = "%d * %d = " % (a, d)
        else:
            solve = d
            c = a * d
            question = "%d / %d = " % (c, a)
        
        answer = False
        while (solve != int(answer)):
            answer = input(question)
            sys.stdout.write("\033[F")
            sys.stdout.write("\033[K")
        score += 1
        if elapsed_time > seconds:
            print("Time\'s up! Your score was %d." % (score))
            break  

play(10)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works better! Quick question, do you know how I would simulate the enter key being pressed? I want the program to automatically press enter if the number entered solves the equation instead of the user having to press enter after inputting the correct answer? I tried import keyboard and keyboard.press('enter'). But I keep getting this: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''